# Form of artificial gravity that is too energy-costly for space habitats

Tags: artificial-gravity

So, to simplify my sci-if universe, I am not putting in space habitats, but I would like some form of artificial gravity to be present for use on space stations and asteroid mines and so on. The problem is, the main form of artificial gravity explored in sci-fi is centripetal force, and this is a very energy-efficient means of producing gravity. Once you get a ring spinning, it’ll just carry on. Ergo, if people use spin-gravity in this universe, they’ll soon start thinking “why don’t we build a huge ring for permanent habitation?” And it’s all Niven rings from then on.

Not wanting to muck about with space habitats, therefore, I need an alternative source of artificial gravity that requires constant energy to maintain, (although not ridiculous amounts), thus making it unfeasible for huge mega-structural habitats. This method need work for space-stations, but 1+ upvote for anyone who offers a system that works for asteroidal/lunar/low-gravity planet surfaces as well.

Comment: How realistic should this be? Handwavium solves a lot...

Comment: Whats wrong with anti-grav generators?

Comment: Things fall down on earth because time moves slower, the lower you go, which morphs into projectile motion. If you just hand wave an expansion to general relativity, some way to convert energy into time, and create a time gradient generator, that might solve your problem. Such a thing, however, might have the same energy requirements as keeping the object under constant thrust to the same g.

Comment: ...even if you had it, why would the people in your setting use such a system instead of spin gravity?

Comment: I'm not sure there is any other concept for artificial gravity that doesn't rely on so much fantasy/handwavium that its energy requirements would be much better than an arbitrary decision. That's to say, you can probably use any artificial gravity concept from any story and simply declare its energy requirements to be exactly what you need it to be.

Comment: if the ring has air in it, it does not just keep spinning, a fluid inside gives it means to dissipate energy. this is why an habitat needs to be spinning along its largest moment of inertia or it will periodically flip. If your habitat is spinning on any other axis it will need frequent adjustments.

Comment: Why would anyone in their right mind choose something that's totally *inefficient* compared to the competition? I can't see how a logical answer can be written. If anything, you need a source of gravity that's *more efficient* than rotational, not less so.

Comment: The standard method of making things more expensive is to tax it. Niven rings and Banks orbitals might just not be built because the people who would do the building haven't figured out how they would charge for it.

Comment: (a) The most common SciFi explanation for artificial gravity is *technobabble.* Like "gravity plating." The only SciFi that uses centripetal force is the stuff trying to be "realistic" and there are only two plausible "realistic" methods: acceleration, which is what centripetal force is, and magnetism. Therefore, (b) why shouldn't this be closed as opinion-based brainstorming? What are your expectations? How will you judge a best answer?

Comment: Please clarify your question to clearly state if you will accept a rotating ring as a solution or not. To be honest, the one and only question mark in your title and your body text has nothing to do with your actual question.

Comment: It also sounds like you want us to invent something for your story.

Comment: Rotational spinning is energy-efficient, but not free. It requires to build a huge ring (the smaller the ring, the worse the side-effects of this kind of "gravity"), which means sending to orbit huge amounts of material. For a spaceship, gravity obtained through a small, highly-efficient ion-thruster would be better, but a space habitat would be presumably in orbit so it doesn't apply. Any kind of antigravity device you invent would make lifting up cargo to orbit easier, thus making rotational habitats factible.

Comment: @John Or you connect the habitat to a counter-rotating shell or habitat drum. A more massive and slower shell is attractive anyways, as you can place industry, radiation shielding, and storage in low G environments.

Comment: @Rekesoft "space habitat would be presumably in orbit so it doesn't apply": if a ship can simulate gravity through continuous thrust, a station could just hover using thrusters. Or fly in a circle, in the absence of an object with sufficient gravity. Which, yes, would be equivalent to spin gravity, just with powered thrusters instead of some kind of passive structure. Which brings us back to: *why*?

Comment: @BMF *I can't see how a logical answer can be written.* - Challenge accepted ;-) Because efficiency is not the only factor. There's also something called **utility**...

Comment: @JBH - gravity plating may actually be a technobabble, but it has sound basis in reality. There were experiments that show possibility of generating gravitational fields using electricity. It's all in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1980s there were some experiments, carried out by Evgueny E. Podkletnov on spinning superconductor disks.
Theory is that if such disk can be spun fast enough (and I'm simplifying it horribly), it will generate local delta in gravity.*

This kills few birds with one stone:

1. it's very expensive in manufacture - we're talking about several hundred thousands RPMs. As required precision and materials are not even dreamt about yet, you have a lot of wiggle room.
2. It's energy intensive
3. It's possible - at least in theory - to produce plates that can be small enough to be used in any setting - from small craft to big station. For size I'm thinking 1 square meter plate, covering area of say 4 square meters, that can generate gravity
4. It can even be a premium feature of a space habitat quarters - so some can have it, some can't. The plate can be set to any gravity one pleases (though negative gravity - I know it's not correct term - is not what you'd think and would be... let's just say it would be very graphic and bad ending for anyone).

Yeah, it can be done the way you'd like it.

> *A year later the same authors presented papers at a meeting of the
> American Physical Society (Reference 17). Buoyed by the apparent
> success of their previous analyses, part of the title of one
> presentation was "A Theoretical Basis for a Principle of Electrically
> Induced Gravitation." In this paper, they used coupled Ginzburg-Landau
> equations to calculate the relative strengths of the electric and
> gravitational fields in superconductors in the presence of magnetic
> and gravitomagnetic fields. They concluded that under certain
> circumstances, a secondary gravitational field could be induced inside
> a superconductor and "provide a basis for the electrical generation of
> gravitational fields in the laboratory."

[Here's the link for more details](https://www.dia.mil/FOIA/FOIA-Electronic-Reading-Room/FileId/170046/)

Answer (score 2):

## Frickin’ Aether

Your vacuum turned out to have tons of this stuff called aether. It makes spaceships have to constantly fire their engines to stay still, otherwise friction moves them. Your gravity ring is like a standard one, but there is several sets of rocket engines (or hall drives/ion thrusters, etc) that push the ring along. It also has engines to prevent orbital decay and such. Massive gravity rings are possible, just there needs to be a proportional amount of engines to radius, thus making them rarer and more expensive.

Theoretically, (assuming your asteroid is reinforced, some of them are just [rubble piles](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubble_pile) and will fall apart) you could attach a structure to an asteroid and rotate it rapidly enough (don’t quote me irl).

Answer (score 1):

Niven's ringworld required the structural material *scrith* be much much stronger than any known substance, so you can't build a fully rotating ringworld and hope for it to hang together. (this is explained in detail in the preface to *Ringworld Engineers*)

what can be done however is build a railroad ringworld
where the constraining  band is stationary and only the habitat platform rotates, now the band doesn't need to support its own innertia so it can be made thick enouigh to constrain the rotating habitat. this brings the "disadavantage" (plot feature) of friction. Meaning that you need an energy input to maintain the fake gravity.

it's not going to prevent more reasonably sized fully rotating habitats

the numbers here:
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/490639/what-length-can-a-metal-wire-cable-hang-vertically
will be the same order of magnitude for the upper limits on practical spinning habitat sizes (so, town or city sized)

At this scale there is no significant air pressure gradient so the fabric needs extra strength to keep that in too.

Comment: If I understand the OP's question correctly, he/she is specifically looking for options *other* than rotating rings. You seem to be advocating rotating rings. Is this a [Frame Challenge](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7097/40609)?

Comment: I'm mainly pointing out that rotating habitats don't scale.

Comment: So... this is a comment and not an answer? (Click that "flag" link and look at the third option.)

Comment: the question: "I dont want Niven rings, I want rings to need energy to make gravity"   the answer "Niven rings are will need energy to make gravity":

Comment: We have very different interpretations about what the OP is asking for. `I am not putting in space habitats, but I would like some form of artificial gravity to be present for use on space stations and asteroid mines and so on.` ... `Not wanting to muck about with space habitats, therefore, I need an alternative source of artificial gravity that requires constant energy to maintain, (although not ridiculous amounts), thus making it unfeasible for huge mega-structural habitats.` ... `upvote for anyone who offers a system that works for asteroidal/lunar/low-gravity planet surfaces as well.`

Comment: I could be wrong, but that all means "no rings" to me. It's tough to put a ring on a low-gravity planet surface.

Comment: it giuess it depends where "megastructure"  starts.

Comment: Possibly, but the OP is specifically trying to avoid megastructures ("thus making [the artificial gravity] **unfeasible** for huge mega-structural habitats"). I'm not trying to be a jerk. I am trying to not flag your answer as "not an answer." I've asked the OP to clarify whether or not rings of any kind may be considered as an answer. I expect not to hear from him/her for another 4-6 hours.

Comment: The question's gonna get closed before the OP gets around to fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

Things fall down on earth because time moves slower, the lower you go, who morphs into projectile motion. If you just hand wave an expansion to general relativity, some energy time correspondence, and create a time gradient generator, that might solve your problem.

This is also, arguably, energy intensive, say, as such to keep such a thing under thrust would have the same energy reqirements. This would place reasnale restictions on such a station. As both fusion and more exotic energy sources can produce quite an amount, this wouldn't restiction such a station size to small constructs, but would place an upper limit. You might be able to put a small asteriod under 1 g with such generators, but that would probably be the max with fusion. This meets your reqirements.

As for why this would be used over spin gravity, perhaps such generators are simple and commonplace. Anything which is used for inertial dampening on a spaceship, say up to twenty g, can support a station of twenty time larger than the ship in question. And if such generators are cheap and easy to produce, all you'd need for a station is a generator, life support system, and a box, and you have a station. This then leads to these stations outcompeting spin stations in how common they are(Being cheaper to produce than spaceships, unlike spinstations). One top of this, perhaps, gravity generators don't interface as well with spin stations.

Comment: Hands down, the best answer - at least in my mind.